# Why are camphor vapours taken in nitrogen gas?

Tags: solutions, sublimation

I have read some examples of "solid-in-gas" solutions in several books. These examples include iodine vapours, camphor vapours etc.

However, one fact that has stuck me is that nearly every book mentions "Camphor vapours in N2" instead of simply saying air. If it's simply "iodine vapours in air", why the distinction for camphor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vapour in gas is not solid in gas, but mixture of gases.

$\ce{N2}$ is not "simply air". Camphor in $\ce{N2}$ means they use nitrogen instead of air, probably to prevent camphor vapour oxidation  by aerial oxygen.